# as3, Event Bubbling, and capture phase

Tags: actionscript-3, events, capture, displaylist, event-flow

Setting the `bubbles` property of an event to `false` means the event does not bubble up the display list at all.

My question is, will the event not go through the capture phase either, or is this not a condition?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the capture and bubble phase will be identical in this case. But since as3 is so old... I don't fully recall, I would test it by listening to capture and see if the event handler responds.

Comment: Hmm, if you can set bubble property of an event, it's you who dispatches the event. If so, there is no capture phase for events that you dispatch, you directly shove them at target. Events that are traversing the display list do have capture phase, but IIRC they all are dispatched by the engine.